# Dynamic cast vs reflection invoke: which poison to pick?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, casting

I'm facing a little dilemma.

I need to repetitively call a given method on many instances of a type, that may or may not exist. Because the method's result will never change for any given instance, I'm caching its return value for future use so as to reduce the overhead and return early on subsequent calls, but still the part that actually does the work needs to call that *method-that-may-not-exist*:

```
var method = Context.Parent.GetType().GetMethod("typeHint");
if (method == null)
{
    token = null;
    _hasTypeHint = false;
    return false;
}

var hint = ((dynamic)Context.Parent).typeHint() as VBAParser.TypeHintContext;
token = hint == null ? null : hint.GetText();
return hint != null;
```

Catching/handling a `RuntimeBinderException` was a major performance bottleneck, so I decided to reflect on the type in question to go and discover whether the method exists or not before calling it.

The specific type of `Context.Parent` is unknown at compile-time, and the possible runtime types don't share a common interface that would have the `typeHint()` method I'm looking for: I need to either invoke the reflected member, or cast to `dynamic` and invoke it directly.

My commit message goes like this:

> removed the possibility for RuntimeBinderException by reflecting on the context type to locate the method to use. **Kept (dynamic) cast because deemed less expensive than reflection invoke**.. could be wrong though.

Which one incurs the least overhead, and more importantly, *why*?

Comment: Why is overhead a concern to you? Are you calling this method multiple times in a tight loop?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm iterating (at least) hundreds of instances (depends on the data) of that type, so yeah pretty much. And profiling it is really like finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: When I face these types of issues I immediately start thinking about asynchronous techniques.  I know that using reflection is expensive, but maybe not so much if you spin off as many threads as you need, right? I don't understand how the dynamic code works and would have to look at it more in depth.

Comment: @JohnPeters right. I forgot to mention, the method in question is called from an asynchronous task. I'm trying to get CPU usage down though, and that code was one of my targets. There are other similar methods, too, so whichever way is better will be applied to other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was curious so I wrote a little program to test:

```
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        int loopLimit = 10000000;
        object hint1;
        sw.Start();
        for( var i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++ )
            hint1 = ( ( dynamic )theObject ).ToString();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine( "dynamic time: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds );
        sw.Restart();
        for( var i = 0; i < loopLimit; i++ )
            hint1 = method.Invoke( theObject, null );
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine( "invoke time: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds );
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Playing with different values of `loopLimit` you'll see that for a relatively low number of calls `Invoke` is faster. As you increase `loopLimit` the dynamic call catches up and then it becomes much faster. Why? Because a dynamic call caches the Expression tree required to do the operation. And in this case, there is only one Expression tree created as I didn't change `theObject` (at a call site there will be only one Expression tree per object type).

So, long story short, if you are only calling a few thousand times or if you have a large variety of object types to test and call, then the Expression tree creation is going to kill your performance and `Invoke` will be better. If objects can be one of a few types and your method is called millions of times, then you may be better off with `dynamic` calls.

Play with the numbers for your particular situation. My guess is that you'll pick `Invoke`.

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea expression trees were involved! So if I understand correctly, I'm actually better off using reflection for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work for you....

```
public async Task<tokenclass> Process(Button Context){
            var x = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                tokenclass tc = new tokenclass();
                var method = Context.Parent.GetType().GetMethod("typeHint");
                if (method == null)
                {
                    tc.token = null;
                    tc.hasTypeHing = false;
                    tc.result = false;                   
                }
                return tc;
            });
            return x;


   public class tokenclass
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public bool hasTypeHing { get; set; }
        public bool result { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't spawning a new task inside a task (the code is already being called from an asynchronous task) incur *more* overhead? I've edited the OP to include that `token` bit, sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: It could but you can test it to make sure.  I have a laptop with 7 CPUs and tons of memory so I'm somewhat insulated from the issue you referred to.